# If $V=U\oplus U'=W\oplus W'$, then is $V=(U\cap W)\oplus (U'+W')$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am interested in knowing whether the following fact is true or not for a vector space $V$, and subspaces $U,U',W,W'$.

> If $V=U\oplus U'=W\oplus W'$, then $V=(U\cap W)\oplus(U'+W')$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wow I guess this is one of those moments where you realise the answer to your own question as soon as you ask it. If $U'$ and $W'$ were orthogonal complements I think it might be true, but they're not so there's more freedom,

A counterexample is $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $U=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}, W=\operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\}$ and $U'=W'=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$. Then $U\cap W=\{(0,0)\}$ and $U'+W'=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$, hence $(U\cap W)+(U'+W')$ is a proper subspace of $V$.

What seems like should be true, is that $(U\cap W)\cap(U'+W')=\{0\}$, or at least I haven't thought of a counterexample to that yet.

Comment: Every vector in $U\cap W$ is orthogonal to every $u' \in U', \ w'\in W'$ and so it is orthogonal to a linear combination of them:that means to  $u' + w'$ aswell.

Comment: Right, so if $U'=U^\perp$ and $W'=W^\perp$ then certainly $(U\cap W)\cap(U'+W')\{0\}$. I suspect this to be true in general though, even when $U'$ and $W'$ are not the orthogonal complements of $U$ and $W$ in $V$, respectively.

This still doesn't say anything about whether $V=(U\cap W)+(U'+W')$ though, does it?

Comment: For your last remark, check the following example: $U=W=\mathrm{sp}\{ (1,0,0) \}$, take $U' = \mathrm{sp}\{ (1,1,0),(0,0,1) \}$ and take $W'=\mathrm{sp}\{ (1,-1,0),(0,0,1) \}$. We have $(U\cap V) \cap (U'+W') =\mathrm{sp}\{ (1,0,0) \}$. I actually think it would be more effective if i explain my intuition: Your question involved $4$ subspaces with $2$ constraints on them. Intuitevely, a vector space of dimension $2$ has too little degrees of freedom to produce an easy counterexample.

Comment: Ah very nice, thank you @Ranc . I'm not sure how I convinced myself that either of the facts I stated ought to be true in hindsight